# horizontal menu with text and images

Tags: html, css, menu, horizontallist

this is my css and html for the menu. I am trying to work out how to make it all horizontal. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

```
ol {
margin-top: 20px;

}

#images {
margin-left: 10px;
}

#images-text {
background: #f5f8ef;
border-radius: 10px;
width: 300px;
height: 40px;
font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
display: inline;

}
```

This is the html

```
  <ol>
  <li class="newbar">
  <div id = "images">
  <img src="images/crowd.png" width ="200" height="180">
  <img src="images/crowd.png" width ="200" height="180">
  <p>

  <div id = "images-text">
  Arctic Monkeys
  </div>
  <div id = "images-text">
  Arctic Monkeys
  </div>
  </div>
  </li>
  </ol>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why `ol` instead of `ul`?

Comment: That piece of HTML code is incomplete or poorly written. As @Paulie_D said, you don't need `ol`

Comment: Also you can't re-use IDs, They must be unique on each page.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a `<ol>`. If you have `<img>` with some text below or above it is good practice to use `<figure>` and `<figcaption>`for the imagetext.

```
<figure>
    <figcaption>
        Image text
    </figcaption>
    <img src="images/crowd.png">
</figure>
```

If you want the image text below the `<img>` just put the `<figcaption>`below the `<img>`.

Than, the **figures** in a `<div>`:

```
<div>
    <figure>
        ...
    </figure>
    <figure>
        ...
    </figure>
    <figure>
        ...
    </figure>
    ...
</div>
```

The **CSS** for every `<figure>`:

```
div figure {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**CSS selectors** usage: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp

example: http://jsfiddle.net/qpk9smm8/